# Voting system with Django, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm kind of stuck, I'm trying to add a voting system to my blog using jQuery, Ajax and Django, but I don't find the best way to do this.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I get the *{{ blog.id }}* in my jQuery script that has to be sent as parameter in the .post method?
2. On my jQuery script, how can I find the *{% static %}* path that I use to change my vote images?

Here is what I got, so far...

## votes.html

```
<a>Total: {{ total_votes }} </a>
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value={{ blog.id }}>
<div class="vote-buttons">
{% if vote.up %}
    <img class="vote-up selected" src="{%static "assets/images/up_on.png"%}"/>
{% else %}
    <img class="vote-up" src="{% static "assets/images/up_off.png" %}"/>
{% endif %}
{% if vote.down %}
    <img class="vote-down selected" src="{%static "assets/images/down_on.png"%}"/>
{% else %}
    <img class="vote-down" src="{% static "assets/images/down_off.png" %}"/>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

## jQuery/Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.vote-up, .vote-down').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('div.vote-buttons img.vote-up').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $.post('myurl', {params:params}, function(response){
                $(this).removeAttr('src')
                   .attr('src',"...") # how to get the template {% static %} path?
                   .removeClass('selected');
            });
        }else{
            # when vote isn't selected
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, to find the unique id of every blog.id I used:

```
var id = $('input[name="blog_id"]', $(this)).val();
```

and as @DGS said, to find the static path I used:

```
<script>
    var static_path = "{% static "assets/images/" %}"
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{ blog.id }}` will become the value of the hidden input with name blog_id so you can find it like so

`$('input[name="blog_id"]').val();`

The static path can be found by looking at the src of one of the images.

Try `$('.vote-up').attr('src').replace('assets/images/up_off.png','');`

You could also just create javascript variables to handle the values from the template for you.

```
<script>
    var blog_id = {{ blog.id }};
    var static_path = "{% static "assets/images/" %}"
</script>
```

and reference those values.

Comment: Thank you, `$('input[name="blog_id"]').val();` returns the last id of the blog.id and not the selected one, am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that I am inside of a loop, so there are many votes displayed. And that's why I am getting the last blog.id. Is there a way in jQuery to find a `$(this)` selected input?